# Is $\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n}{N}\right)^N\left(\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac{a_n}{N}\right)^N≠\left(\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{a_n}{2N}\right)^{2N}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Let
$$G_N= \prod_{n=1}^Na_n$$
and 
$$A_N=\left(\frac{\sum_{n=1}^Na_n}{N}\right)$$
So
$$G_{2N}= \prod_{n=1}^{2N}a_n \\
=\left(\prod_{n=1}^{N}a_n\right)\left(\prod_{n=N+1}^{2N}a_n\right) \\
≤_{IH}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n}{N}\right)^N\left(\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac{a_n}{N}\right)^N$$

I failed to understand why the following is true

$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n}{N}\right)^N\left(\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac{a_n}{N}\right)^N$$

does it imply

$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{a_n}{2N}\right)^{2N}$$

But I use N=10 as example with Mathematica

$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n}{N}\right)^N\left(\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac{a_n}{N}\right)^N≠\left(\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{a_n}{2N}\right)^{2N}$$

See the following image
[image]

Comment: This is one of the reasons why the tag called "algebra-precalculus" ought to be abolished.

Comment: The $N$-exponent  in both sides is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

This, does not imply an equality, but an inequality, with $(A_{2N})^{2N}$, as by the two variable AM-GM, we have
$$\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{a_n}{N}\bigg)\bigg(\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac{a_n}{N}\bigg) \leq \bigg(\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{a_n}{2N}\bigg)^2 $$
Thus we have $$G_{2N} \leq (A_{2N})^{2N}$$
You can figure out how the equality case transfers. Using induction, this suffices as a proof for all AM-GM inequalities with $2^k$ variables, which is what I believe whatever you're reading is attempting to get at.

Answer (score 0):

To show that your equality is false,
all that is needed is an example.

Take
$a_1 = 1$
and
$a_k = 0$
for $k > 1$.

Then
$\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n}{N}\right)^N\left(\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac{a_n}{N}\right)^N
=0
$
and
$\left(\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{a_n}{2N}\right)^{2N}
=\frac1{(2N)^{2N}}
$.

Comment: would you mind elaborate a little bit more? I don't see the trick from your example